# angular material tab content c3js chart not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, angular-material, c3.js

I want to show charts in an angular material tab. But the tab initialization seems to be asynchronous and so c3js can't find the div `#detailed-chart` and my tab remains empty.

**Template**

```xml
<mat-card class="col-xs-12">
  <mat-card-title>
    Detailed Utilization
  </mat-card-title>

  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Chart">
      <div id="detailed-chart" style="height: 200px"></div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Table">
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-card>
```

**Component**

```js
export class UtilizationComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {       
    this.detailedChart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#detailed-chart',
      data: {
        x: 'date',
        columns: [
          ['date'],
          ['room'],
          ['desk'],
          ['office']
        ]
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: '%m.%Y'
          }
        },
        y: {
          tick: {
            format: d3.format('.1%')
          }
        }
      }
    });   
  }
```

}

I also tried to find the div manually and it seems not to exist.

```js
const x = window.document.getElementById('detailed-chart');
console.log('foo', x);
```

**Output**

> foo null

**Question**

What is the angluarish way to load dynamic elements here? Do I neet to create a separate componant for this tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use another lifecycle callback `ngAfterViewInit`.

```js
export class UtilizationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {       
    this.detailedChart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#detailed-chart',
      data: {
        x: 'date',
        columns: [
          ['date'],
          ['room'],
          ['desk'],
          ['office']
        ]
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: '%m.%Y'
          }
        },
        y: {
          tick: {
            format: d3.format('.1%')
          }
        }
      }
    });   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback `AfterViewChecked` to show charts.